# What's an adjective for someone who inspires fear and respect?

Tags: single-word-requests

This person is thought of as "great" and "majestic" because he has done terrible things to get a high job position. He is respected by his employees, and they practically view him as a god. I want to use "awesome," but I feel like it has a positive connotation; I want a negative one. So, I should I keep it or is there a better adjective to describe this person?

Comment: It seems incongruous to apply a negative label to someone worthy of respect.

Comment: forbidding, or formidable? None of them particularly negative, though "formidable" seems to match the description pretty well.

Comment: *Inspiring fear* would be *fearsome*. *Inspiring respect* crops up more in crossword clues, where *admirable* seems to work.

Generally, people inspire either *fear* or *respect*; rarely both. Why *fear* anyone you truly *respect*? Why *respect* anyone you *fear*?

No-one is thought of as anything like *majestic* because he has done terrible things. Fitting *great* to terrible things would be tenuous, at best.

A *high position* or a *top job* could work but a *high job position* suggests unfamiliarity with English.

Under all that, why not keep *awesome*?

Comment: “All shall love me and despair!”  https://youtu.be/spHEw2n9LwE

Comment: “This person is thought of as "great" and "majestic" because he has done terrible things to get a high job position” — This doesn’t make much sense in the normal order of things. If he’s done terrible (that is: horrible, bad, dreadful) things in order to get a top job, then no one in their right mind would call him ‘great’ or ‘majestic’ unless a lot of brainwashing had taken place. Hitler may well have been called ‘great’ and ‘majestic’ by many people in Germany in 1940, but not because he did terrible things.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word ***redoubtable***:

> 1 : causing fear or alarm : formidable
>   2 : illustrious, eminent; broadly : worthy of respect
>
> > *There is a new biography of the **redoubtable** Winston Churchill.*
> >
> > *his next opponent, the reigning champion, would be by far the most **redoubtable** adversary the young boxer had ever faced*
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redoubtable)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Formidable**

> formidable ˈfɔːmɪdəb(ə)l,fəˈmɪdəb(ə)l/Submit adjective inspiring fear
>   or respect through being impressively large, powerful, intense, or
>   capable.